# Add a menu item to KDE Launcher

Tags: kde, menu, kickoff

I've installed `Eclipse Framework` not as a binary package (`tar.gz`), user has only to extract it to a desired directory and start off. I've added eclipse destination path to the global `PATH` variable and I'm able to run eclipse from the command-line without specifying the full path. I also want eclipse to appear on `Kickoff Application Launcher` though, as well as be able to start it via the quick start (`Alt-F2`). What steps should I follow?

I'm using KDE 4.9.4 on Kubuntu 12.04

Thank you!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. Right click on Kickoff.
2. Edit applications...
3. Mark the folder you want it in, e.g. Development. Click on New.
4. Fill in the name you want.
5. Add the actual command and click on the square next to name to change the icon. There is an icon in the eclipse directory.
6. Click Save.

Comment: I would like to choose the icon displayed, for example, some things run a java command, or a wine command.  I would like to download and use the original logo, however, when I hit "browse" in the icon selection area nothing happens

Comment: @csga5000 I think you have to edit you menu item manually. All those items you add via GUI are added to `~/.local/share/applications` folder as `.desktop` files. They are basically shortcuts that are indexed by your menu start applet. Find the correspondent file, open it and add there a line `Icon=/path/to/your/desired/icon` and here you are.

Answer (score 10):

**This was recently updated** (KDE >= 5.19 at least), so the marked answer is no longer correct. To add a new program, do the following:

1. Right click Application Launcher, select `Edit Applications...`
2. Select `New Item`
3. Fill it out and hit Save

Answer (score 2):

Tested on centos-6.5 with kde plasma.
Create an APP_NAME.desktop file as follows(Example for Yed graph editor application ) and place it into /usr/share/applications/.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=yEd Graph Editor
Comment=yEd Graph Editor
Exec=/opt/yed-3.18.2/yedcutor.sh 
Icon=/opt/yed-3.18.2/icons/yicon16.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Comment: that would install it for all users though, if you only want it for a single user create the file in ~/.local/share/applications/ instead